# How can I avoid superposition of same-layered popups in Leaflet?

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, qgis

Whenever I click a marker, there's an odd list of previously clicked popups in a Leaflet project I'm going through, made with QGIS and PostgreSQL, which adds the currently clicked popup to the last element of the list.

I tried being redundant and adding 'autoClose: true' to bindPopup() but to no avail. What I expect is to find a way to clear the old one when the new one is clicked.

Comment: Added information: There's a time interval in which there's no issue at all. Let's say I click on a marker, wait 2-3 seconds, and then press another marker. It works just fine. But there's no way to bundle this product with: "WARNING: Unexpected behavior when clicking too often"